# CSS: if checkbox being child of one div is checked, remove the div being sibling of the first one

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to achieve the following effect without using JS:

I have the following HTML:

```
  <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
  <div class="code-wrapper">
    <input type="text" placeholder="hehe">
  </div>
```

And I want to apply `display: none` on the "code-wrapper" if the checkbox is checked. Also the other way - if the input being child of "code-wrapper" has any value (`input.not(:placeholder-shown)`) then i want to apply `display: none` on the `checkbox-wrapper`

Sadly the following is not working for me:

```
.code-wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.checkbox-wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.checkbox-wrapper input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ .code-wrapper {
  display: none;
}

.code-wrapper input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .checkbox-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

I've tried also with `+` instead of `~` but it doesn't do anything.

Please, teach me :D

Comment: It would require the usage of a parent-selector. However `:has()` still has limited support and is not supported by FF. They current only reliable method for productive use is the usage of JS.

Comment: Yes... Sadly I cannot use `:has()` for this exact reason :/